# Can't install ruby-ldap under Windows/Cygwin

Tags: ruby, installation, rubygems

`gem install ruby-ldap`

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ruby-ldap:
         ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

         /usr/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
--with-ldap-dir=/usr
--with-openldap2
checking for ldap.h... yes
[...]
creating Makefile

make
gcc -I. -I. -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/i386-cygwin -I. ...
[...]
gcc -shared -s -o ldap.so ...
```

The configuration and the compilation works just fine. But the installation throws this error:

```
make install
/usr/bin/install -c -m 0755 ldap.so /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ruby-ldap-0.9.12/lib
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ./lib/ldap/control.rb /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ruby-ldap-0.9.12/lib/ldap
/usr/bin/install: `./lib/ldap/control.rb' and `/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ruby-ldap-0.9.12/lib/ldap/control.rb' are the same file
Makefile:130: recipe for target `/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ruby-ldap-0.9.12/lib/ldap/control.rb' failed
make: *** [/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ruby-ldap-0.9.12/lib/ldap/control.rb] Error 1
```

`./lib/ldap/control.rb` and `/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ruby-ldap-0.9.12/lib/ldap/control.rb` are indeed the same file, but why? Other gems with nativ bindings like `mysql` worked just fine. I reported this as a bug, but some other guy does not have the problem, so the package itself is intact.

If I download the gem and run:

```
ruby extconf.rb
make install
```

The Makefile runs just fine.
It must be my system/configuration. Whats going wrong here?

Comment: I also have the exact same problem, but on Ubuntu 10.04.  All other gems install fine, but this one has the "control.rb are the same file."  Frustrating!

Answer (score 0):

Wow, very oddly, I got this working by downgrading RubyGems and then upgrading it back.  I downgraded it first to match a version (1.4.1) I had on another system that could install ruby-ldap just fine.  I thought this might make it work on my current system, but I got the same error you did.  I upgraded RubyGems back to what I had (1.8.15), then it all magically worked.

So:

```
$ gem update --system 1.4.1  # Downgrade to 1.4.1
...
$ gem update --system        # Go back to current
...
$ gem install ruby-ldap
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed ruby-ldap-0.9.12
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for ruby-ldap-0.9.12...
Installing RDoc documentation for ruby-ldap-0.9.12...
$
```

FYI, I didn't have to use sudo because I'm using rvm and I was installing ruby-ldap into a per-project gemset.

Comment: Sorry, this does not work for me :( Same issue after down/upgrading rubygems.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ubunty, try to perform

```
  sudo apt-get install libsasl2-dev
```

More about it at https://github.com/alexey-chebotar/ruby-ldap/issues/7